# Acumatica Custom Integration/Import Scenarios - "x items have not been processed successfully." - But data inserted correctly

Tags: acumatica

I created a custom Import Scenario that uses the Employee screen. It essentially calls a custom Action I created. The action performs no redirection; it merely creates a new PREmployee record.

The configuration is below:

[image]

When I try to run this in an “Import by Scenario”, I receive an error: Error: x items have not been processed successfully. View name: Employee. No errors appear next to the individual items. Furthermore, the action performs as expected; the PREmployee record is created.

Why might this error be appearing and how might I troubleshoot?

Comment: Open Traces in a new browser tab from tools top right menu. Then run the process again and refresh the Trace page. Is there any details in traces?

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour. Nothing beyond the error mentioned in the post (with a little more detail): 10/4/2021 1:59:07 PM Error:
`Error: 1 items have not been processed successfully. View name: Employee.

   at PX.Api.SyMappingUtils.ImportData(SYProcess graph, SYMappingActive mapping, SYImportOperation operation, SYMappingActive updated)
   at PX.Api.SyMappingUtils.ProcessMapping(SYProcess graph, SYMappingActive mapping, SYImportOperation operation)
   at PX.Api.SYImportProcessSingle.<>c__DisplayClass67_0.b__0()
   at PX.Data.PXLongOperation.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.b__0()` 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Switch off the Commit on the SAVE action. Alternatively, tick the ignore error if all the information was added